# Why does changing my np.array to a list give a different result for my minimax in Connect Four?

Tags: python, numpy, minimax, connect-four

Currently am testing a connect four with minimax implementation and was playing around with numpy arrays and a regular matrix. I tried running the minimax function with a board created with a regular list matrix as opposed to a numpy array and it kept filling up the board state instead of dropping just one piece. I thought creating a shallow copy of the board state and passing it through wouldn't affect things, but I'm a bit stumped on this. It works fine with an numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import math
import copy

ROW_COUNT = 6
COLUMN_COUNT = 7

PLAYER = 0
AI = 1

EMPTY = 0
PLAYER_PIECE = 1
AI_PIECE = 2

WINDOW_LENGTH = 4

def create_board():
    board = [[0 for x in range(COLUMN_COUNT)] for i in range(ROW_COUNT)]
    # board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT,COLUMN_COUNT), dtype=int)
    return board

def drop_piece(board, row, col, piece):

    board[row][col] = piece

def is_valid_location(board, col):
    return board[0][col] == 0

def get_next_open_row(board, col):
    for r in range(ROW_COUNT-1, -1, -1):
        if board[r][col] == 0:
            return r

def print_board(board):
    # print(np.flip(board, 0))
    for i in board:
        print(i)

def winning_move(board, piece):
    # Check horizontal locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r][c+1] == piece and board[r][c+2] == piece and board[r][c+3] == piece:
                return True

    # Check vertical locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT-3):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r+1][c] == piece and board[r+2][c] == piece and board[r+3][c] == piece:
                return True

    # Check positively sloped diaganols
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT-3):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r+1][c+1] == piece and board[r+2][c+2] == piece and board[r+3][c+3] == piece:
                return True

    # Check negatively sloped diaganols
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(3, ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r-1][c+1] == piece and board[r-2][c+2] == piece and board[r-3][c+3] == piece:
                return True

def evaluate_window(window, piece):
    score = 0
    opp_piece = PLAYER_PIECE
    if piece == PLAYER_PIECE:
        opp_piece = AI_PIECE

    if window.count(piece) == 4:
        score += 100
    elif window.count(piece) == 3 and window.count(EMPTY) == 1:
        score += 5
    elif window.count(piece) == 2 and window.count(EMPTY) == 2:
        score += 2

    if window.count(opp_piece) == 3 and window.count(EMPTY) == 1:
        score -= 4

    return score

def score_position(board, piece):
    score = 0

    ## Score center column
    # center_array = [int(i) for i in list(board[:, COLUMN_COUNT//2])]
    center_array = [int(i) for i in [col[COLUMN_COUNT//2] for col in board]]
    center_count = center_array.count(piece)
    score += center_count * 3

    ## Score Horizontal
    for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
        # row_array = [int(i) for i in list(board[r,:])]
        row_array = [i for i in board[r]]
        for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
            window = row_array[c:c+WINDOW_LENGTH]
            score += evaluate_window(window, piece)

    ## Score Vertical
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        # col_array = [int(i) for i in list(board[:,c])]
        col_array = [col[c] for col in board]
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT-3):
            window = col_array[r:r+WINDOW_LENGTH]
            score += evaluate_window(window, piece)

    ## Score posiive sloped diagonal
    for r in range(ROW_COUNT-3):
        for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
            window = [board[r+i][c+i] for i in range(WINDOW_LENGTH)]
            score += evaluate_window(window, piece)

    for r in range(ROW_COUNT-3):
        for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
            window = [board[r+3-i][c+i] for i in range(WINDOW_LENGTH)]
            score += evaluate_window(window, piece)

    return score

def is_terminal_node(board):
    return winning_move(board, PLAYER_PIECE) or winning_move(board, AI_PIECE) or len(get_valid_locations(board)) == 0

def minimax(board, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer):
    valid_locations = get_valid_locations(board)
    is_terminal = is_terminal_node(board)
    if depth == 0 or is_terminal:
        if is_terminal:
            if winning_move(board, AI_PIECE):
                return (None, 100000000000000)
            elif winning_move(board, PLAYER_PIECE):
                return (None, -10000000000000)
            else: # Game is over, no more valid moves
                return (None, 0)
        else: # Depth is zero
            return (None, score_position(board, AI_PIECE))
    if maximizingPlayer:
        value = -math.inf
        column = random.choice(valid_locations)
        for col in valid_locations:
            row = get_next_open_row(board, col)
            b_copy = board.copy()
            drop_piece(b_copy, row, col, AI_PIECE)
            new_score = minimax(b_copy, depth-1, alpha, beta, False)[1]
            if new_score > value:
                value = new_score
                column = col
            alpha = max(alpha, value)
            if alpha >= beta:
                break
        return column, value

    else: # Minimizing player
        value = math.inf
        column = random.choice(valid_locations)
        for col in valid_locations:
            row = get_next_open_row(board, col)
            b_copy = board.copy()
            drop_piece(b_copy, row, col, PLAYER_PIECE)
            new_score = minimax(b_copy, depth-1, alpha, beta, True)[1]
            if new_score < value:
                value = new_score
                column = col
            beta = min(beta, value)
            if alpha >= beta:
                break
        return column, value

def get_valid_locations(board):
    valid_locations = []
    for col in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        if is_valid_location(board, col):
            valid_locations.append(col)
    return valid_locations

def pick_best_move(board, piece):

    valid_locations = get_valid_locations(board)
    best_score = -10000
    best_col = random.choice(valid_locations)
    for col in valid_locations:
        row = get_next_open_row(board, col)
        temp_board = board.copy()
        drop_piece(temp_board, row, col, piece)
        score = score_position(temp_board, piece)
        if score > best_score:
            best_score = score
            best_col = col

    return best_col
```

Testing here, dropping just one piece and then running minimax to get the best piece.

```
board = create_board()
print_board(board)
print("\n")
game_over = False
if is_valid_location(board,1):
    row = get_next_open_row(board,1)
    drop_piece(board, row, 1, PLAYER_PIECE)
    print_board(board)
    print("\n")
checker, score = minimax(board, 5, -math.inf, math.inf, True)
if is_valid_location(board,checker):
    row = get_next_open_row(board,checker)
    drop_piece(board, row, checker, AI_PIECE)
    print_board(board)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Where are you making the shallow copy? It needs to be a deep copy since it's a list of lists.

Comment: You could also just remove the piece before you return from the minimax function.

Comment: @Barmar Ah you're right! I had to make a deep copy. Using numpy, I could just do board.copy() but after changing it to a list matrix I had to call copy.deepcopy(board).